# Can I force certain computations to occur despite their result not being used in the kernel?

Tags: optimization, cuda, compiler-optimization, microbenchmark, ptx

I'm trying to analyze the "cost" of a certain part of the computation performed by a CUDA kernel of mine. There is, of course, the use of profiling; but what I'm trying to determine is how much I could gain by investing in speeding up, or replacing, that certain part.

I want to make that estimation by determining how the kernel behaves when I cut out that part - not replacing it with something more efficient, just skipping it. So, my kernel might look like (semi-pseudocode, although technically valid CUDA C++):

```
// -- snip --
auto data = read_data(input);
auto massaged_data = massage(data);
auto result = heavy_lifting(massaged_data); // (*)
update(output, result);
```

and I replace the `(*)` line with

```
auto result = dummy_result();
```

which default-initializes, or sets to 0's, etc.

Unfortunately, ,this approach does not work, because either the nvcc frontend or ptxas optimize away most code related to the data that's not used: Most of `read_data()` and most of `massage()` go away, and perhaps even all of them.

I also tried marking some variables and fields volatile - either the result, or intermediate values during its computation, or both; but this didn't help.

My question: Can I force `massaged_data` to be computed, despite it never being used later, and without otherwise disabling any compiler optimizations?

Note: If you believe this *can* be done with `volatile`, but that perhaps I did not properly volatile-up my program, this would be a valid answer, but try to give a concrete example of how to actually do it right, and mention potential "gotchas" if you know of any.

Comment: no, you can't do that. The compiler is working against that objective. `volatile` in CUDA device code simply says "reads and writes that the compiler chooses to make to this variable must not be passed through the L1". You can however "conditionally write" the data to global space.  If you choose your condition such/properly/carefully, the write may not occur, the data may never actually get used, but still calculated, and it may never get written to the global space, either. The conditional check may need to be data-dependent. The compiler may be too smart to just pass it via kernel arg.

Comment: [example/discussion](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/to-perform-performance-testing-how-to-prevent-side-effect-free-code-from-being-optimized-away-by-the-compiler/266576/5)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Hmm... conditioning on a runtime value which can't be know in compile time. It would indeed be tricky, because the compiler might place the condition check before the computation to optimize the other code path. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, if you make it simple to do so.  My reference to "data-dependent" meant "calculation data", i.e. that which you were trying to calculate without it being optimized away. If you make the conditional based on that, the compiler cannot pre-eliminate anything.  I've given an example above.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I force massaged_data to be computed, despite it never being used later, and without otherwise disabling any compiler optimizations?

Yes. Paulius Micikevicius proposed a design pattern in the early days of CUDA performance analysis that looks something like this:

```
__global__ void mykernel(....., T *dummy, int benchmark=0)
{

    .....

    // Some code

    .....

    // Code you want to conditionally disable for benchmarking
    T result;
    if (benchmark > 0) {
         result = dobigcalculation();
    }

    // More code

    if (benchmark > 0) *dummy = result;

}
```

Because the result of `dobigcalculation` is connected to a global memory write, and because benchmark doesn't resolve to an immediate constant at compile time, the optimized won't identify anything as dead code and strip it out.

Is it perfect? No.

You can potentially change the register profile of the kernel and you are adding at least one extra argument, which might change how the compiler builds your code. The code reordering heuristics can also make it hard to replicate the true flow of unmodified and modified code in some cases, meaning you really need to checked the PTX which the compiler emits. And while the design pattern is trivial for cases where `dobigcalculation` returns a simple POD type, it can be harder to devise an assignment operation to truly ensure that parts of your code are not silently stripped out if the function is operating on a class or a reference, rather than a return value.

But it is about the best you can do to measure the impact of a given code stanza in fully optimized code.

Comment: But if benchmark = 0 at runtime, won't the calculation be skipped?

Comment: I thought that was what you were implying in your question. Obviously you are free to change either the default value or the sense of the flag to taste

Comment: So, my point is that there are some thing I want to skip (`heavy_lifting`) and some that I don't `read_data` and `massage`. But - the latter two are useless if `heavy_lifting` is gone. Now, if, in your code, I put the latter two before the if-then, the compiler can, and should, optimize by moving them inside of the then-block - and they will again not be computed when benchmark=0.

Comment: If you have a more concrete example that the nonsense stream of consciousness code in your question, by all means add it. The point of this design pattern is that by using an int instead of a Boolean you can have a complex truth table that will normally defeat the optimizer. But as I said in the answer, its not perfect, but about as good as you can do